# docker container can't communicate to other container on the same network

Tags: docker, containers

I have two images that should communicate with each other. The first image is the web API, and the second image is the web itself.

Before I build and run the images, I create a new network called `nat` using the command:

```
docker network create nat
```

After this, I start to create my images which I called `image-api` that runs on port 8080 and `image-web` that run on port 8081.

Then, I run the `image-api` image using the command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:8080 --network nat image-api
```

I mapped the container port `8080` to my host port `3000`. I tried to access the localhost port `3000` in my browser and it's running without an error and giving me the response as it should be.

The problem here is, my second image, the `image-web` image. I try to run it using the command:

```
docker run -d -p 3001:8081 --network nat image-web
```

When I try to access `localhost:3001` in my browser, it's running, but not giving the data from `image-api` container. When I try to logs the `image-web` container, it's giving me an error like:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND image-api
```

Just in case, I try to access the `image-api` container from my `image-web` container using URL like this:

```
http://image-api/ping
```

Here's my image-api Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install

FROM node:14
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
WORKDIR /server
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules /server/node_modules
COPY server.js .
```

And here's my image-web Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

FROM node:14
ENV IMAGE_URL=http://image-api/ping
EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
WORKDIR /web
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules /web/node_modules
COPY /src .
```

Just in case, I already tried to run both of them without docker, and they run as it should be in my local computer.

EDIT:

I've also tried to run the container using name like this:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:8080 --network nat --name imageapi image-api
```

And try to access it using:

```
http://imageapi/ping
```

But it's still giving me the same error

SOLUTIONS:

As being pointed out by @davidMaze on the answer. After running our container using `--name` tag. I can access my container using `http://imageapi:8080/ping`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify a `docker run --name` when you start the container.  Since you can run multiple containers from the same image, Docker doesn't automatically assign a container name based on the image name; you need to set it yourself.

```
docker run -d -p 3000:8080 --network nat --name image-api image-api
docker run -d -p 3001:8081 --network nat --name image-web image-web
```

Once you set the container name, Docker provides an internal DNS service and the container will be reachable by that name from other containers on the same network.

[Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) in the Docker documentation describes this further, though mostly in contrast to an obsolete networking mode.

Comment: Hi, i've already run my image-api image with the name of "imageapi" and access it using "imageapi/ping" but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: You need to also include the port number the process inside the container is listening on, `http://image-api:8080/ping`; if you don't it defaults to port 80.  `-p` options aren't used for inter-container connections.

Comment: @BeingShame This answer should work for you. One thing i would like to point out is that you are not using the `-P` option in `docker run` command to make use the `EXPOSE` option specified in the `Dockerfile`, so you might as well just get rid of it.

Comment: @Yousaf did you mean get rid of the ```EXPOSE``` in my Dockerfile ?

Comment: @DavidMaze oh so that's why thank you for your answer

Comment: @BeingShame yes. You can get rid of it or you can stop using `-p` option and use `-P` to expose the port specified in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @Yousaf I've just checked on the docs that ```-P``` is different with ```-p```. With ```-P``` we publish the exposed port to the random port ? i understand. Thank you for you info